# barra lateral usando position-fixed con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css-grid-layout

Quiero tener una barra lateral del lado izquerdo fija y que el contenido principal sea donde se haga el scroll, le agregue a mi aside la clase position-fixed pero cuando hago esto, el contenido principal queda encima de la barra lateral y no se ve,intente solucionarlo con margin left pero no es buena opcion si pensamos en el responsive,como lo puedo resolver,gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la barra lateral ocupa 2 columnas de las 12

Aqui el codigo:

```
 <div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="row">
        <aside class="lateral col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2  position-fixed">
            <h1 class="text-center">lateral</h1>
        
        </aside>
        <section class="principal col-xl-10 col-lg-10 col-md-10">
            <div id="barra_arriba">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="pestaña col-xl 1"></div>
                    <div class="barra col-xl-11">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <section id="contenido">
                <div class="maqueta">
                    <div class="container">
                       <div class="row mt-5">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed porro quas ipsa, consequatur fuga facere esse est laborum omnis, rerum sapiente nemo assumenda, eaque beatae. Alias reiciendis quod expedita cupiditate?</p>
                       </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </section>
            
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo respuestas a preguntas similares en SO, son comunes un par de opciones:

1. Mantener el `position-fixed` en el `ASIDE` y dándole un [`offset`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) al `SECTION.principal`. Pero si varias el tamaño de la ventana te vas a dar cuenta enseguida de que no es nada *responsive*. Supongo que con [*media queries*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) podrías apañarlo.
2. Con la clase [`sticky-top`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#sticky-top) aplicada a un `DIV` dentro del `ASIDE`. Aunque si los contenidos de la columna izquierda no caben en la pantalla, el scroll que manda es el de la columna más alta, lo cual creo que es un poco confuso.